# Сохранение данных SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-shared-preferences

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с парой небольших проблем, решение которых не нашел на буржунете.

1. В play market'е есть приложение, у которого небольшие данные хранятся с помощью SharedPreferences и изменяются пользователем. Большое количество пользователей жалуется, что после выхода из приложения, или сворачивания его, данные удаляются. Хотя на моем гаджете все работает исправно - все сохраняется. С чем это может быть это связано?
2. Если использовать SharedPreferences — как можно запретить пользователям использовать сторонние программы "взломщики", которые позволяются редактировать данные SharedPreferences ?

**Обновлено:**

Сохраняю и использую так:

```
public void setDataInt(String key, int value) {
    sPref = getSharedPreferences(DATA_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putInt(key, value);
    ed.commit();
}

public int getDataInt(String key) {
    sPref = getSharedPreferences(DATA_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
    int data = sPref.getInt(key, 0);
    return data;
}
```

**Друзья**, вопрос актуален. Есть ли какие-нибудь мысли по поводу первой проблемы?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 1) показывайте как сохраняете - можно будет что то придумать.
2) храните настройки зашифрованными или с добавлением кодов проверки или на сервере.

Comment: @KoVadim, 1) Обновил вопрос. 2) Каким алгоритмом оптимальнее шифровать численные значения?

Comment: код, который вызывает setDataInt, где находиться?

а как шифровать... это дело такое. Я бы лично использовал стенографию. То есть, ввел какой-то дополнительный параметр с непримечательным именем и хранил там к примеру сумму (crc32) важных полей. При записи это поле естественно будет обновлятся. При чтении его можно время от времени проверять.

Если оно не совпадает, то не объязательно сразу подымать панику. Мало чего...

А шифровать данные иногда очень неудобно - сложно отлаживать.

Comment: @KoVadim, все находится в одном отдельном классе, который расширяет Activity, а уже MainActivity расширяет этот отдельный класс.

Comment: ок, зайдем с другой стороны. Что такое [Activity Life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) слышали?

Comment: Да, конечно.

Comment: Возможно проблема в переменной DATA_NAME. Она должна быть уникальной и тут можно использовать имя пакета.

Comment: @Deadkenny, DATA_NAME - это константа, значение у которой "data_app". Думаете, что в системе у большого количества пользователей может уже существовать с таким именем? Но на сколько мне известно — можно назвать как угодно, так как все данные хранятся в xml, а этот файл находится в папке с названием моего пакета.